# Is it standard to talk about salary and conditions with ALL shortlisted candidates?

Tags: interviewing

As per titles, I just got an interview with the HR on my soft skills and he also explained me the salary and conditions (pretty much in detail, it took 30 mins for the interview and other 30 for salary etc.)

He told me the does this with every shortlisted candidate. Is this really standard, or should I consider it as a good sign?

Comment: This is common. I'm prepared to discuss it even with non-short-listers if the topic comes up. This sounds like their standard process and isn't an indicator of anything.

Comment: Isn't being shortlisted already a good sign?

Comment: I don't know how we can answer whether he is lying to you or not, which is what this question boils down to.

Answer (score 6):

It doesn't matter if X% of them do this. The question is "does that company/HR person do this?"

I would expect some level of discussion of salary and benefits when talking to the HR person. They work with these issues everyday. Most employees and mangers only know some of their benefits, and none of the benefits that don't apply to them.

One reason to discuss this is to set levels regarding salary and benefits. If you hate the retirement program, or you think the salary may be too low they want to know. You questions can also let them know which things you like or at least plan to use.

So back to your question. If you trust their statement then discussing these items means nothing about your chances. If you think they lied, then your chances are good that you will get an offer.

Answer (score 4):

#### Of course this is standard.

Imagine if you weren't willing to work for less than $150k, and the job had a salary band that only went up to $70k.  If that's the case, why would the company want to waste any more of their time (or yours) on a candidate that's not going to fit the open position?

Generally, the HR interview is there to weed out candidates that aren't good fits on the face of things.  That usually amounts to "Doesn't come remotely close to the required skillset", "Possesses a personality we feel would be terrible for our culture", and... "Salary expectations aren't in line with position."  No sense in having any technical interviews if there's already a hard reason why they couldn't get the job regardless.

Comment: I totally get it, but this was AFTER TWO technical interviews, with many staff members including the boss, and not before.

Comment: @Bayer Kevin is still correct. They can have that salary discussion at any point in the process. There may be 5 excellent candidates remaining, and they are trying to see who will work for less.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this really standard,?

Mostly yes. Some form of compensation discussion is always part of the early engagement in order to identify a major mismatch. 30 minutes is a bit on the long side, but that may just be the style of this recruiter and/or it's an unusual comp package.

> or should I consider it as a good sign?

It's hard to answer without knowing the specific company. It's also a pointless question: what would you do with the answer? Until you have a written offer in hand, assume that it will not work out and act accordingly, i.e. keep looking (if you are active) and keep doing your current job as usual.

Comment: It took a bit long because he also explained to me how I will be evaluated, the dates such evaluations, and things that are immigration related such as if I am bringing my girlfriend with me.